# I pointed the file.choose() command to a file titled "mytest.r". How do exit from this now?

Tags: r, file

I am a novice trying to learn R using the swirl library. I entered the below command after which the screen just lets me type endlessly.

```
file.choose("mytest2.r")
```

Could someone help me understand what exactly is expected here and how to exit out of this? `mytest2.r` is just a blank file.

Comment: `file.choose` doesn't seem to expect a path to a file as its argument, but is instead meant to be called without an argument, like `file.choose()`. As to what is happening, most likely a file manager window popped up, to prompt you to select a file. Do you see it? If yes, select a file there, then you should return at the R prompt automatically, with the full path to the selected file printed above

Comment: What "environment" are you using? RStudio Desktop on Windows, RStudio Server in a web browser, R started at the command line directly (and if yes, on which Operating System), or other?

Comment: It's working on Ubuntu 19.04 and I don't even have a file with that name. Just press <Cancel> and the file choose window closes, with an error.

Comment: Sorry, guess it was just me being stupid then. I am assuming a file open dialog opened in the background and I did not notice it. Thank you guys for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to try it again and got the expected result, ie, the file open dialog popped up.